# Adding values to a list below a threshold number

Tags: python, database, list

I have a list of random data and a threshold:

```
threshold = 3
data = [2,2,2,2,2,5,5,2,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,4,5,4,3,4,5,3,3,7,8,2,2,2] # data
timestamp =[] 
for i in range(len(data)):
    timestamp.append(i)
print(timestamp)
```

I am trying to extract timestamps that are below the threshold but, if a range of consecutive timestamps (less than 4 timestamps (<4)), between 2 time ranges below the threshold occurs, we also treat it as below the threshold

As such, this example should return:

```
belowthreshold = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,25,26,27]
```

So we can see that the consecutive `5,5` is skipped and treated as under threshold since values before and after it are under threshold

Currently, my method is:

```
belowthreshold = []
for j in range(len(data)):
    if data[j] < threshold and data[j]: # check if greater than threshold, meaning energy is being used at home
        belowthreshold.append(j) # add this time to a list
```

However it quite clearly only extracts values less than the threshold.

What is the best way to approach this?

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Your question need more details and explanation

Comment: Sorry, which detail would you like to me to elaborate on?

Comment: Your example output does not match the input or your description, neither when considered as indexes into the previous list or as the values themselves. For example, index 9 is `2`, but not included in your output - the same for 11 - 13.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I just changed it

Comment: You need to define what do you mean by the term **value** and explain your output according to your expectation.. re-visit your question and modify it

Comment: I think I understand what you mean: You want the index of every member of the list which isn't  part of a run of at least three numbers which are at least as large as the threshold? I have posted a solution below!

Comment: Thanks for the comment what you say it true, I expanded on your points

Comment: Why are 23 and 24 not in your output? From index 23, you have values `[7, 8, 2]`. The number of consecutive values more than the threshold is less than 4.

Comment: @not_speshal, thank you for raising this point, I will reword it so to clarify that I dont want this

Answer (score 6):

Try with list comprehension using `itertools.zip_longest`:

```
import itertools

output = [i for i, (x, y, z) in enumerate(itertools.zip_longest(data,data[1:],data[2:],fillvalue=0)) if x<threshold or y<threshold or z<threshold]

>>> output
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]
```

###### Edit:

To take into account that the "consecutive" timestamps can be on either side, you can use `itertools.groupby` using a custom key to check if the value is less than the threshold.

This splits the data into the following groups: `[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]`, `[5, 5]`, `[2, 2, 2, 2]`, `[3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 3, 3, 7, 8]`, `[2, 2, 2]`

```
output = list()
i = 0
for k, v in itertools.groupby(data, key=lambda x: x<threshold):
    values = list(v)
    if k or len(values) < 4:
        output += [i+x for x in range(len(values))]
    i += len(values)

>>> output
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 25, 26, 27]
```

Comment: Very elegant solution.  This almost works. The problem is that if there are >3 numbers in a row above the threshold it will return the index of the first and last of those instead of rejecting all of them.  However, the question was a little vague in the area and so I'm assuming this was the intention in the question.  

Use this to create the truth table:  output = [(i, x, y, z, (x<threshold or y<threshold or z<threshold)) for i, (x, y, z) in enumerate(itertools.zip_longest(data1,data1[1:],data1[2:],fillvalue=0))]

Try with  data = [2,2,2,2,2,5,5,5,5,2,2,3,4,5,6,4,5,4,3,4,5,3,3,7,8,2,2,2]

Comment: The second solution should address the issue after your edit :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a temporary list to store steps when they're above threshold and you can add them to the result list if they remained above only 3 or less steps, otherwise you reset this temporary list. Here we go:

```
threshold = 3
data = [2,2,2,2,2,5,5,2,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,4,5,4,3,4,5,3,3,7,8,2,2,2] # data
steps =[] # 'time stamp'
for i in range(len(data)):
    steps.append(i)
print(steps)

belowthreshold = []
temp_above_threshold = []
consecutive_above_counter = 0

for j in range(len(data)):
    if data[j] < threshold:
        if consecutive_above_counter < 4: # add only if less than 4 steps were above threshold
            belowthreshold = belowthreshold + temp_above_threshold
        # reset counter and temporary list
        consecutive_above_counter = 0
        temp_above_threshold = []
        belowthreshold.append(j) # add this time to a list
    else:
        consecutive_above_counter += 1
        
        if consecutive_above_counter < 4:
            temp_above_threshold.append(j)
        else:
            temp_above_threshold = []
print(belowthreshold)
```

**edit**: I tried to bring a **simple solution** following your code, **without** adding **extra packages complexity** that might be difficult to keep track later.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to replicate your output with the following code:

```
def below_threshold(threshold, list_of_value):
    indices = set()
    for i in range(2, len(list_of_value)):
        if all(list_of_value[k] >= threshold for k in [i, i - 1, i - 2]):
            indices = indices.union({i, i-1, i-2})
    return set(range(len(list_of_value))).difference(indices)

print(below_threshold(3, [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 3, 3, 7, 8, 2, 2, 2]))
```